# GWT: eclipse debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-archetypes

I'm trying to migrate a netbeans/ant gwt project to an eclipse/maven gwt project.

For that I used the archetype [gwt-maven-archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes), to create a maven project, and after that I copied the sources.
I had succesfully been able to run codeserver and the application itself, using maven comands, as suggested by the archetype author. I even can debug on chrome dev console.

The problem, is that I want to debug from eclipse, and it seems eclipse gwt plugin, doesn't support the current structure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You're using super dev mode correct?

Comment: Try SDBG: https://sdbg.github.io/

Comment: @YoussefLahoud - Yes, that's right.

Comment: @ElHoss, I tried it, but I only could make it work on a single maven module application. With the above mentioned archetype I have a main project with 3 maven modules(client, server and shared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, giving up this archetype, and I'm using now simple webapp maven archetype. I figured it out, but still a little tricky on my project.

So, as @ElHoss, has suggested I'm using [SDBG](http://sdbg.github.io). Besides that, I'm not using jetty, but my own tomcat installation, so I've followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9270Yqt-5I) instructions, together with the SDBG page video's instruction.

At the end, I have 3 Running Configuration items:

- The one that starts Tomcat;
- The one that starts codeserver;
- Chrome Launcher, as instructed on SDBG page.

If you need plus information, please comment.

Thanks.